# Converting string date for new date constructor

Tags: javascript, date

I have a string date with the format YYYYMMDD (20170603). There are no hyphens in this string, it is just one string. I want to convert this string so it can be used by a date constructor. I want to do the following `new Date(2017,06,03)` What is the most efficient way of doing this? Note: I want my date to be in YYYY MM DD format

Comment: @SurabhilSergy No this is not like that question because I'd like my string to be exactly the way it is in date format

Comment: 4 answers, all but 1 wrong. The equivalent of "20170603" is `new Date('2017', '06' - 1, '03')`. This is a duplicate of many other questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use substring():

```
new Date( parseInt( str.substring(0,4) ) , 
          parseInt( str.substring(4,6) ) -1 , 
          parseInt( str.substring(6,8) ) 
        );
```

Like the comments show, you could well leave out the parseInt:

```
new Date( str.substring(0,4) , 
          str.substring(4,6) - 1 , 
          str.substring(6,8) 
        );
```

Comment: The month needs to be -1 and *parseInt* is redundant. This is a duplicate of many other questions.

Comment: @RobG You're right. To do the month though, you would need the parseInt.

Comment: There is no need for parseInt. The `-` operator coerces the arguments to number, so `"5" - 1` returns `4` (as does `var n = "5"; --n`).

Comment: @RobG You're right. I didn't know you could do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.prototype.slice()`

```
let month = +str.slice(4, 6);
let date = new Date(str.slice(0, 4), !month ? month : month -1, str.slice(6))
```

Comment: @RobG Good point. See updated post

Answer (score 0):

```js
var dateStr = "20170603";
var match = dateStr.match(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/);
var date = new Date(match[1] + ',' + match[2] + ',' + match[3])

console.log(date);
```

Comment: The month should be -1